# Compiling OpenCV without sse for use in ROS

Tags: opencv, sse, ros

So I've run into a problem that seems to be related to using OpenCV in ROS on a processor that doesn't support SSE. Specifically, the problem occurs whenever trying to use OpenNI or freenect to interface with an Xbox Kinect. Any time I try to launch either one, I will get an "Illegal Instruction" error. From what I've read, this issue can be tracked back to opencv and that it uses SSE, which is not supported on my processors (Vortex86DX on a Roboard RB100). I've found instructions on how to compile OpenCV from source and using flags to compile without SSE, but cannot figure out how to use this in ROS. Does anybody know how to use a custom compiled version of OpenCV in ROS to alleviate this problem?

Thanks!

If you need any further information, please ask.

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting the "illegal instruction" error trying to use opencv and ROS on an old CPU, try building the opencv libraries w/o SSE3, and then copy them over the ROS versions.

For example, something like this:

```
$ cd ~/opencv-2.4.9
$ mkdir build && cd build && cmake -DENABLE_SSE3=OFF .. && make && sudo make install
$ sudo cp `ls /usr/local/lib/libopencv*.2.4.9` /opt/ros/hydro/lib
```

Then see if it worked:

```
$ python
> import cv
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem.
Check that the older libraries are not in a ROS library path, such as `/opt/ros/groovy/lib` .

You may also update your environment variables to make sure that the new libs are loaded before.